# Cakephp: Time, diff not working as expected

Tags: php, cakephp, time, timestamp

I am building a task manager application where the user can start/stop a task. And I want to know when the user started it, when stopped it and how long task was running.

In the `appcontroller.php` I have set this timezone:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Athens");
```

But in `taskscontroller.php` when I save the time that the task has been started:

```
$now = FrozenTime::now();
$task->date_start = $now;
```

It is saved 2 hours ahead in the database (the field in the database is timestamp type).So when I click start at 9:00:00 I see that is saved as 11:00:00 in the database. Same when I click stop:

```
    $now = FrozenTime::now(); 
    $task->date_end = $now;
```

Again it is saved 2 hours ahead. But in my application when user clicks stop I want to calculate the time that the task was running. So I am calculating like this:

```
$task->total_minutes = ($now->diff($task->date_start))->format('%i'); //minutes
```

But even though date_start is : 2019-03-18 11:43:47
and date_end is : 2019-03-18 11:45:33

I get total_minutes: 58 which is obviously wrong... Why I get all these faulty behaviors?

Comment: Please always mention the exact CakePHP version that you are using, and in case DB problems are involved, mention the DBMS and its version too - thanks! Also please try to provide reproducible examples, like a single code snippet instead of 4 that are distributed over different classes and actions with data from external sources, where nobody knows if/when/how things are being invoked exactly.

Comment: That being said, if you're using MySQL, start with using `DATETIME` instead of `TIMESTAMP` to rule out timezone conversion, quote: "_MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.)_" **https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html**. btw, [**`DateInterval` objects**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) won't give you the _total_ number of minutes, but _the remainder_ of the timespan in minutes.

Comment: @netdev Just a piece of simple advice, please be aware of the difference between your MySQL Timezone and your PHP TimeZone. More reading click [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/synchronize-php-mysql-timezone-configuration/)